# How to use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in Apache ignite

Tags: ignite

I'm working with apache ignite, where multiple client nodes(spring boot applications) are running. I want to acquire lock on a cache/table entry to select & update atomically so that no other process can update it. Similar to what we have in MYSQL **SELECT FOR UPDATE**

## Usecase description

I have records in cache/table with **TO_BE_PROCESSED** status. My cron job picks the record and updates the record in **IN_PROGRESS** status and processes the entry as per business logic. As I have multiple client instance running. I don't want to duplicate the processing against each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite 2.x does not have SQL transactions, so there's no `SELECT FOR UPDATE` but it does support transactions when using the key-value API. You'd need to do something like:

```
try (var tx = ignite.transactions().txStart()) {
  cache.get(recordToUpdate1);
  cache.get(recordToUpdate2);

  // ... do processing ...

  cache.put(recordToUpdate1, value1);
  cache.put(recordToUpdate2, value2);

  tx.commit();
}
```